# Not able to generate pdf using Servlet and Ajax

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, servlets

My scenario is to download a PDF file. I'm sending two types of response based on success or failure case. I am not able to generate the report as its from Ajax. How can I solve it?

### Server side

```
public void generatePdf(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,@PathVariable("dealId") String dealId) throws <Exceptions>{

try {
    byte[] documentBytes = // Some bytes
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=Sample.pdf");
    response.setContentType("application/pdf");
    response.setHeader("Expires", "0");
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "must-revalidate, postcheck=0, pre-check=0");
    response.setHeader("Pragma", "public");
    response.setContentLength(documentBytes.length); 
    ServletOutputStream out = null;
    try {
        out = response.getOutputStream();       
        out.write(documentBytes);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error(e);
    }
} catch(Exception e) {
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    ServletOutputStream out = null;
    out = response.getOutputStream();
    String msg = "Exception occured in pdf generation"; --> I want to catch this message in Ajax response
    out.write(msg.getBytes());
    out.flush();
    out.close();
}
}
```

### Ajax

```
$.ajax({
          url: url,           
          cache: false,          
          timeout: 20000,
          success: function(response, status, xhr){ 
                var ct = xhr.getResponseHeader("content-type") || "";
                if (ct.indexOf('html') > -1) {
                    console.log("11");
                  //do something
                }                    
              },
 }
```

P.S: I don't want using `window.open` as I would like to catch the exception too, in case of failure case.

Comment: "not able to" isn't an error message or problem description. What actually goes wrong when you try this?

Comment: @Adyson, I want to generate pdf or get the exception if occured. This should be done through Ajax

Comment: That's not a problem description either. I know what you want to do. You've got some code...so please explain what difficulty you're facing. Explain what debugging you've done and what error messages and/or unexpected behaviour you're experiencing while trying to achieve your goal